# Python if or not

Tags: python, if-statement

i have a an if statement like the one below

```
if (not(fullpath.lower().endswith(".pdf")) or 
    not (fullpath.lower().endswith(tuple(settings.imageExtensions)))) :
```

The problem is that none of those works and it gets in the if function if the file endswith .pdf or one of the other extensions.
What is the best way to do this?
FYI i cannot put .pdf in the tuple

Comment: Why not print the various parts of your condition to see what the issue is?

Comment: `if not fullpath.lower().endswith(tuple(settings.imageExtensions)+(".pdf",))`

Comment: Can you explain what this expression is _supposed_ to do in words? Currently it is _always_ `True` unless `fullpath.lower().endswith(".pdf")` and `.pdf` is in `settings.imageExtensions`. Which doesn't seem useful

Comment: You can add .pdf to the tuple by putting it in its own tuple. `if not fullpath.lower().endswith(tuple(settings.imageExtensions) + ('.pdf',)):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to switch to `and` based on [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if not(fullpath.lower().endswith(".pdf")) and not (fullpath.lower().endswith(tuple(settings.imageExtensions))) :
```

In other words, the following are equivalent

```
not A and not B == not (A or B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `splitext` here

```
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> fullpath = "foo.jpg"
>>> splitext(fullpath)[1].lower()
'.jpg'
```

so consider:

```
if not splitext(fullpath)[1].lower() == '.pdf' and not splitext(fullpath)[1].lower() in (".jpg", ".gif"):
```

clearer to factor out the splitext

```
extension = splitext(fullpath)[1].lower()
if extension != '.pdf' and extension not in set(settings.imageExtensions):
    ...
```

Comment: Is there any actual advantage using  a set?

Comment: It's getting beyond the scope of the question, but it would help if you make the set just once - ie factor it out and use the set multiple times instead of doing a linear search each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `pdf` to `settings.imageExtensions` and make one single call.

```
exceptions = (".pdf",) + tuple(settings.imageExtensions)
if not fullpath.lower().endswith(exceptions):
```